# Is Google Progressive Web App suitable for Survey style application?

Tags: android, web, progressive

I am planning to build a survey style questionnaire app that will run on android devices. I am not too keen on creating Android apps and recently came across PWA framework of Google.

Can anyone suggest if this is an ideal solution to build an offline survey style questionnaire app, the requirement is users will download a new questionnaire before going in field which would have different set of questions and choices and will take responses that could be around 100-500 per questionnaire in offline mode and they will come back to office and connect with internet and sync with central database.

My question is whether PWA can provide this offline feature and more importantly how much space is provided for a PWA to use on devices, is the space limited to couple of MB's like the Microsoft MVC solution?

Thanks,
Anurag

Comment: Did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding offline capabilities:
You can use service workers for such requirement. If you are only targeting modern devices with updated browsers, offline capabilities shouldn't be a problem.

Regarding Storage:
You can either leverage web storage API or indexedDB. In either case, you may read: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/ to know the limits for each. Actual answer depends on platform and browser.

If you are only targeting mobile app and can take care of app distribution you can also consider Ionic for developing a hybrid app. 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/

Also, check out:
https://github.com/pazguille/offline-first : Everything you need to know to create offline-first web apps.